# Limiting redirect parameter to specific domain

Tags: php, url-redirection

Using PHP to set a Location header to redirect (e.g., upon login after being signed out) can be insecure if the redirect does not specify a domain. Here is an example:

```
header('Location: ' . $_GET['redirect']);
```

Is there a simple way (not a whitelist) to ensure that the redirect not leave the domain. Maybe something like:

```
header('Location: /' . $_GET['redirect']); //start forward slash guarantees domain cant change?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe something like:
>
> ```
> header('Location: /' . $_GET['redirect']); //start forward slash guarantees domain cant change?
> ```

No, a leading forward slash does **not** protect you against [open redirects](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet).

An attacker could query the script as...

```
https://yoursite.example/file.php?redirect=/malicious.example
```

...resulting in `Location: //malicious.example` which is treated as a protocol-relative URL that your browser will understand as a redirect to `https://malicious.example`.

This notation also works for URLs in other contexts, e.g. HTML links:

```
`<a href="//malicious.example">...</a>`.
```

> Is there a simple way (not a whitelist) to ensure that the redirect not leave the domain.

An alternative simple approach to @David's answer is checking for a slash and a subsequent alphanumeric character, or the beginning sequence `/./`. Both can never lead to the representation of an absolute URL.

Note that in older versions of PHP you also had to sanitize a user-supplied header value for newlines/carriage returns as you might otherwise enable header injection attacks.

---

From your follow-up comment:

> what if it started with a protocol and hostname? eg, `header('Location: https://domain.com' . $_GET['redirect'])` is there a way around that?

This is only safe if you enforce that the first user-supplied character is a slash. Otherwise, a simple attack would be `.malicious.example`, redirecting to the attacker-controlled subdomain `https://domain.com.malicious.example`. Alternatively, `@malicious.example` works too, since that turns `domain.com` into the username for authenticating with the domain `malicious.example`.

Comment: that is good to know about the forward slash and alphanumeric character. what if it started with a protocol and hostname? eg, `header('Location: https://domain.com' . $_GET['redirect']` is there a way around that? im just curious; thanks!

Comment: @tau I expanded my answer on your example.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is trivially bypassable:

```
http://yoursite.com/page.php?redirect=/www.google.com
```

results in a redirect of:

```
//www.google.com
```

Which is a valid URL.

You should parse the URL using a function like `parse_url` then reconstruct a sanitized URL with the path components you want.  For example, you could use just the `path` and `query` fragments to build a URL that redirects only within the current protocol, port, and host.